# Extracting output to use for a variable in bash

Tags: bash, variables, awk, sed, scripting

After running an `fdisk -l`, I want to be able to extract the volume group name to input later in a bash script. Example below:

```
fdisk -l | grep /dev/mapper/vg_palpatine
Disk /dev/mapper/vg_palpatine-lv_root: 105.1 GB
vgextend /dev/vg_$vg_name $partitioned_drive
```

I want to extract *palpatine* out of the `fdisk -l` output and input it as my `$vg_name` variable. I've been suggested a few different solutions, like sed, cut and awk, but I don't have much experience with those. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

We can whole input string with the volume name only. To do this, we ask `sed` to replace (`s///`) regex matching with second expression:

```
vg_name=$(fdisk -l | grep /dev/mapper/vg_palpatine | sed -rn 's/.*vg_(.+)-lv_root.*/\1/p')
```

Regex explanation:

`.*` -> Any number of characters.

`vg_(.+)-lv_root` -> Capture the volume name as group 1.

We use the `.*` to match the whole input string, then we use group 1 (`\1`), which captures the volume name only, as substitution.

Note that if you want to use `$vg_name` on a different script you need to `export` it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
vg_name=$(fdisk -l | grep /dev/mapper/vg_palpatine | sed -n "s/.*\/\(.*\)-.*/\1/p")
vgextend /dev/$vg_name $partitioned_drive
```

Comment: No need for grep, sed can search fine.